# What is the type signature of this Haskell function?

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference

I wrote a function to check whether a number is prime or not:

```
prime n = prime' n 2 (floor (sqrt n))
     where prime' n c u | n `mod` c == 0 = False
                        | c > u = True
                        | otherwise = prime' n (c+1) u
```

I can't figure out what the type signature of this function should be. At first I thought it should be this:

```
prime :: Integral a => a -> Bool
```

But then I get errors when compiling because `sqrt` expects a `Floating a` and `floor` expects a `RealFrac a` instead of an `Integral a`. When I remove the type signature, it compiles, but the function does not work:

```
*Euler> :t prime
prime :: (Integral a, RealFrac a, Floating a) => a -> Bool
*Euler> prime 5

<interactive>:1:0:
    Ambiguous type variable `t' in the constraints:
      `Floating t' arising from a use of `prime' at <interactive>:1:0-6
      `RealFrac t' arising from a use of `prime' at <interactive>:1:0-6
      `Integral t' arising from a use of `prime' at <interactive>:1:0-6
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
```

How can I make this function work?

Comment: Hah, prime', read that aloud. ;-)

Comment: read it as prime-apostrophe first, then i realized prime-prime :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you use `sqrt` on `n`, which forces `n` to be a floating-point number; and you also use `mod` on `n`, which forces n to be an integer. Intuitively, from looking at your code, `n` *should* be an integer, so you can't directly call `sqrt` on it. Instead, you can use something like `fromIntegral` to convert it from an integer into another numeric type.

```
prime :: (Integral a) => a -> Bool
prime n = prime' n 2 (floor (sqrt (fromIntegral n)))
     where prime' n c u | n `mod` c == 0 = False
                        | c > u = True
                        | otherwise = prime' n (c+1) u
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to go over one last bit that the other answers haven't covered...

```
*Euler> :t prime
prime :: (Integral a, RealFrac a, Floating a) => a -> Bool
```

The typechecker has inferred that `prime` can take an argument of type `a` as long as `a` is an instance of the `Integral`, `RealFrac`, and `Floating` classes all at once.

```
*Euler> prime 5

<interactive>:1:0:
    Ambiguous type variable `t' in the constraints:
      `Floating t' arising from a use of `prime' at <interactive>:1:0-6
      `RealFrac t' arising from a use of `prime' at <interactive>:1:0-6
      `Integral t' arising from a use of `prime' at <interactive>:1:0-6
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
```

When you ask it to `prime 5`, however, it complains that none of the default types of `5` can satisfy those conditions.

It's quite possible that you could write your own

```
instance (Integral a, RealFrac b, Floating b) => Integral (Either a b) where ...
instance (Integral a, RealFrac b, Floating b) => RealFrac (Either a b) where ...
instance (Integral a, RealFrac b, Floating b) => Floating (Either a b) where ...
```

(and you'd also have to add `Num`, `Ord`, `Real`, `Fractional`, etc. instances), and then `prime 5` would be acceptable, since there would exist a `5 :: Either Integer Float` which does satisfy the type conditions.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could change the upper-bound test:

```
prime n = prime' n 2
    where prime' n c | n `mod` c == 0 = False
                     | c * c > n = True
                     | otherwise = prime' n (c+1)
```

Btw, you don't need `n` as an argument to `prime'` since it is constant through all calls.

Comment: Further micro-optimization: `prime n = prime' 2 4 where prime' c s | n `mod` c == 0 = False | s > n = True | otherwise = prime' (succ c) (s+c+c+1)`: that is, avoiding multiplication by using "n^2 = 1 + 3 + .. + (2*n-1)".  It's probably not worth it though :)

Answer (score 2):

You can change `(sqrt n)` to `(sqrt (fromInteger n))` to make the function work as expected. This is needed because the type of `sqrt` is:

```
sqrt :: (Floating a) => a -> a
```

so it is wrong, for example, to do:

```
sqrt (2 :: Int)
```